# Влияет ли начальное значение итератора цикла на время компиляции в C++?

Tags: c++

```
for(int j = 0; j < 100;)  
{
    for (int i  = 0; i < 500; j++)
    {
        //Что-то происходит
    }
}
```

// Тот же самый цикл, только i объявлен 500.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
{
    for (int i = 500; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        //Происходит тоже самое, что и в цикле выше
    }
}
```

Повлияет ли то, что я объявляю "i" не с 0, а с 500 на скорость компиляции? При этом сам "i" не участвует в циклах. Я не использую переменную в теле цикла.

Comment: Просто плохо разбираюсь в том, что в моем коде влияет на время компиляции. Соответсвенно мой код улучшить можно, а как, сам не знаю. Смотрю на свой код и думаю, что может повлиять. Может есть какая-то литература, которая поможет мне?

Comment: Похоже, вы путаете время _компиляции_ с временемя _выполнения_.

Comment: Почему вас беспокоит время компиляции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

До тех пор, пока значения помещаются в одинаковые типы - абсолютно никакой разницы. И то, компилятор имеет право это оптимизировать и поместить в стандартный тип, или наоборот развернуть цикл в линейный код.

А вы с какими целями интересуетесь? Предполагаете, что будет значительное ускорение, в 5-500 раз? Или академический интерес, к примеру, какое время тратит компилятор на чтение 1 или 3 символов из файла с кодом?

---

> Просто плохо разбираюсь в том, что в моем коде влияет на время компиляции. Соответственно мой код улучшить можно, а как, сам не знаю. Смотрю на свой код и думаю, что может повлиять. Может есть какая-то литература, которая поможет мне?

Максимальное ускорение **работы программы** дает выбор другого, более оптимального, алгоритма. К примеру, кэширование результатов внутренних циклов, распараллеливание, выбор алгоритма с лучшим O(n), и т.п. Если у вас рабочий код, то вы можете разместить вопрос с просьбой о его инспекции (см. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/инспекция-кода/info](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info))

Если же вопрос именно о **времени компиляции**, то задавайте отдельный вопрос, описывайте конфигурацию, приводите замеры времени и т.п.

---

В любом случае, заниматься подобными микро-оптимизациями (с 500 на 0) - бессмысленно и даже вредно.

Comment: Вот например у меня есть функции, которые я написал. Как узнать сколько времени компилятор проводит времени в этих функциях ?

Comment: Вы путаетесь в терминологии. Время (скорость) компиляции - это за сколько секунд из исходного кода компилятор соберет вам EXE-шник. Вас же, судя по комментариям, интересует время (скорость) работы приложения. Она определяется "профилированием" - т.е. измерением времени затрачиваемого на разные части кода. В простейшем случае - опрашивайте таймер до и после куска кода - получите время затраченное на выполнение этого куска кода.

Answer (score 0):

Если значение `i`, как вы сказали, не используется в теле цикла, то практически любой современный компилятор сгенерирует один и тот же код для цикла по `i` - просто абстрактный цикл, который выполняется 500 раз.

Но тем не менее, вопросы о "скорости" не имеет осмысленного ответа в отрыве от конкретного окружения.